# Is there a way to execute multiple UI.Vision macro at the same time (more than 2)

Tags: python, powershell, google-chrome, rpa, kantu

I did a program in Python using a PowerShell command that launches multiple (between 2 and 10) Chrome instances in incognito mode using multiprocessing and running the UI. Vision "API" which is a local html file that executes a UI.Vision macro according to some parameters.

The program is working fine for a maximum of 2 Chrome instances; but when I try more good open the Chrome instance and UI. Vision macro but...
The macro doesn't execute. I don't know whether the issue is from the UI.Vision side... or perhaps this is from the config of my setup (which is a good one).

Does someone have the answer to this problem?
Or did someone try that before?

nb: According to my contract I am unable to share code but I don't think the issue is from my code, to be honest. All you have to know is that it's working using multiprocessing that runs the PowerShell commands because I don't have the right to use selenium.

I try with Firefox and I am unable to open multiple instances of the UI.Vision.
I check my CPU and this is the problem maybe...
I tried to do it with a really small macro and still.
I tried in headless mode to avoid conflict or whatever but still.